# how can i solve this error when i install docker toolsbox for my windows?

Tags: laravel, docker, virtualbox, laradock

I installed dockertools box in Windows 7, and i get error message after run it.

the error like this

[image]

what can i do for fix this? thanks

Comment: Did you checked if Virtualization is enabled in your Bios ?

Comment: yes, i already checked, after that i run the dockertools box and nothing change, still like that error